# Is 5 in 100,000 the same as 50 in 1000,000 from a Bayesian perspective?

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, proportion

I am learning about bayesian reasoning and I was having a discussion with a friend about it.
My friend asked me this question, which I couldn't answer (this is not a homework, I am an adult learning bayesian statistics for the fun of it)

There are 2 cities. City A, and City B both are on State C.

- 1 million people live on City A. Every year 50 people are murdered in that city.
- 100,000 people live on City B. Every year, 5 people are murdered in that city.
- Where should I live?

Now, I know that if were to randomly pick a person from State C, and that person had just been murdered, there is 90% probability that person would come from City A.

So, that seems to point out that I should live on B... But the thing is, I have not been murdered, and from that perspective, the murder rate of both cities looks the same: 5 for every 100,000 habitants. 
Does that mean that I am really equally likely to be murdered in A and in B, even while, if I had just been murdered, I am more likely to had been murdered on A?

What if every year, 6 people were murdered in B? Would that mean that I should live in A (even while if I had just been murdered, I was most likely murdered in A?)

Comment: Analogously, is one in one the same as one million in one million? In any view of the world (frequentist, Bayesian)? Of course not. One heads in one throw is far different than a million heads in a million throws. The first case gives more weight to your prior belif. You can view this as an instance of Bernstein Von-Mises theorem.

Comment: @Yair The information provided in this question is not in the form of data: it consists of assertions about actual rates, perhaps long-term estimates.  Thus it would be incorrect to treat them as if they were counts, as you suggest.

Comment: It's perhaps helpful to clarify two things: *what the data is* and *what the quantity of interest is*. As @whuber points out, the data is in the form of city-specific counts and population sizes. If the quantity of interest is P( murdered | city), then you maybe want to infer the true murder rate for each city from the data you mention, plus - if you're being bayesian - anything else you might know, distributional or numerical, about murders in cities in state C. Then, conditioning on the data, you can examine how the posterior over this quantity responds to having more/less data about a city.

Comment: In the first instance you're getting a distribution over possible values of your quantity of interest. So, not a point estimate of the murder rate or a decision, although you can get these from that distribution with extra assumptions.

Comment: In your final paragraph you're noting that p(city | murdered) is not p(murdered | city). True! Only the second one is useful for making a decision to live in a city.